# Problems with the Angular ngIf

Tags: angular

I would like to change the text that comes as "Thor: Ragnarok" to "THOR (RAGNAROK)" but I don't know how to do it. The information that comes from the movies comes from an external API that brings the name of that movie that way but I want to change it so that it shows the other way. Any ideas?

Attached photo of how the Api arrives.

[image: Services component]

Then the information comes to character in this way. What looks like a comment is something I tried but didn't work.

[image: Character component]

And this is the html.

[image: HTML]

Comment: Please, no code screenshots. Paste + format the relevant code (and just the relevant) directly in your post. By the way, when it's just about displaying the title in uppercase: apply a css class with `text-transform: uppercase` to the element.

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I'm new to posting on StackOverflow and I don't quite know how to ask good questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: better read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to change the text, something like this

```
fromatName(str: string) {
  if(!str)
    return str;

  ..... code to format your text....
}
```

In your html:

```
<mat-card-title>
   {{charater.id}} {{fromatName(character.name)}}
</mat-card-title>
```

Comment: Try to avoid how much as possible using functions in template. Prepare the data in required format, before to be rendered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. It does in a concrete and understandable way for me what I wanted. Thank you :) And I'll keep in mind what you've said about the template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your componente call the service:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getAllCharacters().subscribe(characters => {
     characters.forEach(c => c.name = c.name.toUpperCase());
     this.characters = characters;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I understand the power that onInit has in Angular as a constructor in any programming language. Little by little and I will understand it :)

Comment: Not really, `ngOnInit` is a 'life cycle' of your component (at component initialization do something there). For any class you have the `constructor` using same key, where you can inject services from your app or 3rd party libraries, etc

Comment: It's still a messy thing for me but thank you.